# check text file content with perl

Tags: perl

I am seeking some feedback as to the efficiency of this code and also how to remove the qualifying file from the @FilesToUse array if it is moved.

I am loading all files in a directory to the @FilesToUse array. I then need to check each file and see if line 7 says 'BATCH' if it does i would like to move the file and then also remove the filename from the @FilesToUse array so when i use that array later on it doesnt have the BATCH file name in it. I hope I stated this question clearly.

The text files are approx 10Mb and i typically have 2 files to process per day.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
 #Loop thru the files that were found and delete the one that is BATCH

       foreach $FileToUse (@FilesToUse)    #Loop at the file level
       {

open (FH, $TheInputDir . $FileToUse) or $MailMsg = $MailMsg . "ERROR: Could not open input file: $FileToUse \n";

          while (<FH>)                     # Loop at the line level within each file
          {
             $TheLine = $_;
             chomp($TheLine);
             $LineCnt++;

             if ( $LineCnt == 7 and substr( $TheLine, 1, 6 ) =~ /BATCH/ ) {

                move( "$TheInputDir$FileToUse", "$TheBatchMoveDir" )
                   or $MoveFail = 1;

                if ( $MoveFail == 1 ) {
                   $MailMsg = $MailMsg
                      . "ERROR: Failed to move $FileToUse to Batch folder!\n";
                }
                else {
                   $MailMsg
                      = $MailMsg . "Moved BATCH file $FileToUse to Batch folder\n";
                }
             }

             last if $. == 7;
          }
       }
```

Comment: A sample of the input file would be useful as well.

Comment: Rather than removing an element, wouldn't it be better if it never got added to `@FilesToUse` in the first place?

Comment: Also, could you create a [mcve] for this question?

Answer (score 0):

> how to remove the qualifying file from the @FilesToUse array

We can remove an element from an array with [`splice`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html), but we need the array index for this.
You could change the outer loop to

```
       foreach $findex (-$#FilesToUse..0)  #Loop at the file level
       {
           $FileToUse = $FilesToUse[-$findex];
```

and insert

```
                splice @FilesToUse, -$findex, 1;
```

where you want to remove the file element.
(The array is processed from last to first element to avoid the "missing element syndrome" when an index is deleted - see also [How do I completely remove an element from an array?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1871))

Answer (score -1):

I would clean up the semantics:

```
         $LineCnt = $.;

         if ( $LineCnt == 7 ) {
            close FH;

            if ( substr( $TheLine, 1, 6 ) =~ /BATCH/ ) {

               move( "$TheInputDir$FileToUse", "$TheBatchMoveDir" )
                  or $MoveFail = 1;

               if ( $MoveFail == 1 ) {
                  $MailMsg = $MailMsg
                     . "ERROR: Failed to move $FileToUse to Batch folder!\n";
               }
               else {
                  $MailMsg
                     = $MailMsg . "Moved BATCH file $FileToUse to Batch folder\n";
               }
            }

            last;
         }
```